# What are words for higher orders of 'quadratic'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't find anything upon a quick Google search. In English, there are double, triple, quadruple, etc. How about for quadratic, does it have higher order forms, for example maybe 'tridratic'(I'm just making up words)? As in the 'quadratic' in quadratic equation, this is one of the example I can think of, maybe there are other usages I don't know.

Comment: *constant, linear, quadratic, cubic, quartic, quintic, sextic, septic, octic, nonic, decic*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial

Comment: @DanBron I wish I could give you the best answer.

Comment: [A common question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267264/how-do-you-explain-cubic-growth-of-a-function)